# Using session object to create CriteriaBuilder to create a CriteriaQuery since CriteriaAPI is deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I'm learing Hibernate and have already built a project using Hibernate and I've created a SessionFactory object and then a Session object using the SessionFactory's openSession method.

While trying to use Criteria API of Hibernate I found that it has been deprecated since 5.2.3 Final version which I'm using.

I do not want to create an EntityManager object using EntityManagerFactory as I'm already using SessionFactory.
This is what I've done.

```
---
try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession()) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaQuery<Transaction> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Transaction.class);

        Root<Transaction> root = criteriaQuery.from(Transaction.class);

        criteriaQuery.select(root);

        List<Transaction> transactions = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();


        for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
            System.out.println(transaction.getTitle());
        }
---
```

This surely isn't the optimal way to do it as Hibernate is built on top of JPA and the best way to do it would be using EntityManager. Is there any other workaround to what I'm doing instead of having to create an EntityManagerFactory and then a EntityManager object using the said factory as It would mean I'd have to make a lot of other changes to the program design.

Comment: Why learning something that is already deprecated and why not using EntityManager? It is your choice, but then don't tag the question with `jpa.

Comment: Yes. I realized it later that wanting to continue using something that will no longer be supported just so I don't have to change a few program designs was a very wrong approach. I made the necessary changes and shifted to using EntityManager. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, unfortunatelly there is no such an API which replaces the Criteria API in Hibernate. Please consult the [5.1 documentaion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/query-criteria/Criteria.html) which explains it.
I also wanted to use SessionFactory instance to handle queries but it is recommanded to use EntityManager for building queries programatically.